# Worksheets does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an excel visual basic macro.

My Problem is that this code works:

```
Dim x As String
x = Worksheets("Abgabe").Cells(20, 3).Value
```

But this doesn't:

```
Dim y As Worksheet
y = Worksheets("Abgabe")
```

Also if I use ActiveWorkbook the code doesn't work.

```
Dim y As Worksheet
y = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Abgabe")
```

I'm getting this error:

> Object variable or With block variable not set

What could be the problem?

Comment: Ah, the most common error in VBA ... :-)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Were you referring to "Worksheets does not work"? ;)

Comment: No, the "Needs SET for Object assignments." programming error.  Because the compiler cannot detect the error, virtually every VBA programmer has done it at one point or another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > > Dim y As Worksheet
> > >
> > > y = Worksheets("Abgabe")

Use this (You have to use `Set`)

```
Dim y As Worksheet
Set y = Worksheets("Abgabe")
```

**From MSDN** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490.aspx):

```
Set Keyword: In VBA, the Set keyword is necessary to distinguish between 
assignment of an object and assignment of the default property of the object.
```