# VBA - Delete a row from another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Yesterday I sought assistance on:

1. From a VBA macro creating a new workbook, Workbook 'B'
2. Copying over a row of data from Workbook 'A' to Workbook 'B'
3. Saving Workbook 'B' in an appropriate format before closing it

Yesterday's post ([VBA - How to copy row in Excel from one workbook to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230025/vba-how-to-copy-row-in-excel-from-one-workbook-to-another)) presented a solid solution to my problem.

Since then I have progressed further with my code and have a new requirement of it. I now need to have a section of code that will remove a copied in row from Workbook 'B' depending on if a value in cell Ai of Workbook 'A' sheet1 matches that in cell Ai of workbook 'B' sheet1 (i is an integer variable which gets incremented). This piece of code runs much after the section of code which copied in the row, and where the primary row has since been updated with new information, hence why this may seem a bit backward.

What I have below should give you an idea of what I have:

```
...
Do Until IsEmpty(newBk.Sheets("Bad Records").Range("A" & extFileRowCount))
     If newBk.Sheets("Bad Records").Range("A" & extFileRowCount) = _
        mainBk.Range("W" & sdRow).Value Then
        'then delete the row and reinsert
        '***** Stuck here. How do I remove the row? *****'    
         newBk.Sheets("Bad Records").Range _
            ("A" & extFileRowCount).remove '???
            newRowCount = newRowCount + 1
            mainBk.Rows(sdRow).Copy newBk.Sheets _                
                 ("Bad Records").Rows(newRowCount)
      Else
           extFileRowCount = extFileRowCount + 1
      Loop
...
```

I think I have the algorithm correct, but I'm stuck on how to remove the row. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

QF

Comment: There is no obligation to accept an answer. Answers are not closed on SO as they are on other, paid, sites. Questions always remain open. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/asking-upvote-for-accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure why you have this line in the loop

```
mainBk.Rows(sdRow).Copy newBk.Sheets _                
("Bad Records").Rows(newRowCount)
```

But to delete the rows you can use this code (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Delrange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '

    For i = extFileRowCount To 1 Step -1
        If newBk.Sheets("Bad Records").Range("A" & extFileRowCount) = _
           mainBk.Range("W" & sdRow).Value Then

            If Delrange Is Nothing Then
                Set Delrange = newBk.Sheets("Bad Records").Rows(i)
            Else
                Set Delrange = Union(Delrange, newBk.Sheets("Bad Records").Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not Delrange Is Nothing Then Delrange.Delete

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: The reason I have "mainBk.Rows(sdRow).Copy newBk.Sheets("Bad Records").Rows(newRowCount)" in the code is because as I posted yesterday you provided a way to copy a row from Workbook 'A' to Workbook 'B'. As I describe in this post, I have a new requirement to delete and reinsert a row (based on said match condition). I will look at your untested code and give it a go. Many thanks.