# Error in defining a new cell using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I get an error when I try to execute the following code if the `cell(10,1)` is never used.

```
Dim targetCell As Range
targetCell = Cells(10, 1)
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `Can anyone tell me why?` You already have the solution but if you want to know the "WHY" part then please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196620/worksheets-does-not-work/10196646#10196646

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just started reading a VBA book several days ago (this may be wrong):

```
Set targetCell = Cells(10, 1)
```